# How to free memory of python deleted object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

It seems python3.5 does not completely free memory of any deleted object, this may because of python internally maintaining some kind of memroy pool for reusing purpose, however, I don't want to reuse them, and I want to free them to make memory available for other programs running on linux.

```
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
11.47265625
>>> d = {x:x for x in range(10**7)}
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
897.1796875
>>> del d
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
15.5859375
```

This is just a toy example,  the real problem is on a running server,  taking 20GB of unfreeable memory.

here is another example:  (wd1 is a dict of dict with string keys)

```
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
28.1796875
>>> wd1 = {x:{i:i for i in d} for x in k}
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
682.78125
>>> del wd1
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
186.21484375
```

Comment: You have no control over memory management in python (or any other modern language with automatic or semi automatic memory management).

Comment: This is really a problem when we need to use python on a server program,  how to modify python3.5's source code to make it usable on servers?

Comment: Just a thought, but what about using subprocess or the multiprocess modules to do the big chunks of work?  Once a Linux process terminates, wouldn't you get all your memory back?  *how to modify python3.5's source...* seems like a no-starter, to me, at least.

Comment: oh, and you may also want to look at *weakref* and see if any of it applies to your issues.

Comment: 20GB is way to much for some maintaining memory. You should show the code where you get "unfreeable" memory. You probably still keep references to all of your objects.

Comment: @Daniel I can't post production code here,  but the sample code is very similar, except "d" is a 1000x  larger dict,  and being updated inside a function.

Comment: @JLPeyret  I can't use child process, because multiprocessing does not have a shared dict

Comment: If you repeat those instructions *again*, what is the result?  I.e. if you repeat those steps multiple times in the same python process, does the return value of `psutil.Process().memory_info().rss` level off, or does it keep growing?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser on python interpreter, it grows a little but not much,  on  server,  it grows a lot by repeating it.

Comment: @JLPeyret 
    d = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary({x:x for x in range(10**7)})
get a "TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'int' object ",  if it WeakKeyDictionary can not be used on 'int' or 'str' ,  I don't know how to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1316767/608639)

Answer (score 6):

Once you delete an object it is available to garbage collected rather than deleted immediately - so just give it some time and it will free up or trigger a `gc.collect()` to speed things up.

```
python.exe
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> import gc
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.2890625
>>> d = {x:x for x in range(10**7)}
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
359.13671875
>>> del d
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.5234375
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.4375
>>>
```

Just for reference the Python 3 shell is actually more like ipython 2 in that there is a certain amount of storage taken up with history, etc., just for reference:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.1875
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.20703125
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.20703125
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.20703125
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.20703125
>>> 22*3
66
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.25390625
>>> import gc
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.25390625
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.171875
>>>
```

Next Morning to check if doing dict update in a function is different:

```
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.1484375
>>> D = {}
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.1484375
>>> def UpdateD(d, v):
...     """ Add the text and value for v to dict d """
...     d[v] = str(v)
...
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
13.16015625
>>> for x in range(10**7):
...     UpdateD(D, x)
...
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
666.6328125
>>> del D
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
10.765625
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
12.8984375
>>>
```

So it looks like your production code might be hanging onto a reference that you still have to track down.

Comment: Just as a note for people not familiar with gc, it will temporarily block so definitely not something to call in the middle of time sensitive logic.

Comment: I waited 30 minutes, and ran gc.collect() several times,   it still shows 15.5859375,  not freed

Comment: the same thing happens in a server process, not just on python3 shell,
unfreeable and not gc collectable